# How to find duplicate objects by multiple properties and merge them?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I’m writing a verify function for data normalize between collection in MongoDb
I have an object: as below:

```
class ReleaseTime{
  private Date startDate;
  private Date endDate;
  private List<String> regions;
}
```

I have to gather all ReleaseTime object that has same `startDate`, and same `endDate` then merge the Regions list together

I have tried the code below but it just group by startDate

```
expectedAvailabilities = ungrouppedReleaseTime.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ReleaseTime::getStartDate,
                    Function.identity(),
                    (ReleaseTime tb1, ReleaseTime tb2) ->
                    {
                        tb1.getRegions().addAll(tb2.getRegions());
                        tb2.getRegions().clear();
                        return tb1;
                    })
            ).values();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative way of doing what you want without using streams:

```
Map<List<Date>, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
ungrouppedAvailabilites.forEach(a ->
    map.computeIfAbsent(Arrays.asList(a.getStartDate(), a.getEndDate()), // or List.of
                        k -> new ArrayList<>())
       .addAll(a.getRegions()));
```

This uses [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to group regions of `ReleaseTime` objects by start and end dates.

In case there are repeated regions among the grouped `ReleaseTime` objects and you don't want duplicates, you could use a `Set` instead of a `List`:

```
Map<List<Date>, Set<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
ungrouppedAvailabilites.forEach(a ->
    map.computeIfAbsent(Arrays.asList(a.getStartDate(), a.getEndDate()), // or List.of
                        k -> new LinkedHashSet<>())
       .addAll(a.getRegions()));
```

Note that I'm using `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` to keep elements in insertion order.

---

**EDIT:**

If you need `ReleaseTime` objects instead of only their regions, you could achieve it with one extra step:

```
Map<List<Date>, ReleaseTime> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.forEach((k, v) -> 
    result.put(k, new ReleaseTime(k.get(0), k.get(1), new ArrayList<>(v))));
```

This assumes there's a constructor for `ReleaseTime` that receives all the attributes:

```
public ReleaseTime(Date startDate, Date endDate, List<String> regions) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.regions = regions;
}
```

Comment: Great idea but I need one more step to map it back to ReleaseTime object. Thanks

Comment: It works like a charm.  Seems I need to learn more about those new functions :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the grouping as :

```
// Collection<ReleaseTime> ungrouppedAvailabilites...
Collection<ReleaseTime> mergedRegionsCollection = ungrouppedAvailabilites.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> Arrays.asList(t.getStartDate(), t.getEndDate()),
                Function.identity(), ReleaseTime::mergeRegions))
        .values();
```

where `mergeRegions` is implemented as :

```
ReleaseTime mergeRegions(ReleaseTime that) {
    List<String> mergedRegions = this.getRegions();
    mergedRegions.addAll(that.getRegions());
    return new ReleaseTime(this.startDate, this.endDate, mergedRegions);
}
```

Note: To avoid mutating the existing objects, you can use the implementations as:

```
ReleaseTime mergeRegions(ReleaseTime that) {
    return new ReleaseTime(this.startDate, this.endDate,
            Stream.concat(this.getRegions().stream(), that.getRegions().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Sure. No problem. I thought that was the intention `tb1.getRegions().addAll(tb2.getRegions());
                        tb2.getRegions().clear();` as well. The code something like `return new ReleaseTime(this.startDate, this.endDate,
                    Stream.concat(this.getRegions().stream(), that.getRegions().stream())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));` should be good otherwise.

Comment: I get an incompatible error when trying this solution:
Required List<> but concat was inferred to Stream<T> ....

Comment: @HaiNguyen given that `List<String> regions`, the solution should work, if you place the `mergeRegions` implementation in the `ReleaseTime` class itself.